serial port error in arm64 Raspberry Pi5 single board computer
when i open my electron app i have encounter this error-
/tmp/.mount_rPosIOLkyfQh/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/build/Release/bindings.node: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I have give all the permission but still have the same error
